# I couldn't seen to find a way to click on the Login using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to setup a bot to login to my account, however I couldn't seem to find a way using Python and Selenium.

Here is the website: www.shopee.sg

[image]

I've tried hover action, finding xpath. but none of it seems to work.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://shopee.sg/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('E:/users/Asashin/Desktop/Bots/others/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)

actions = ActionChains(driver)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="English"]').click()

time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_class_name('shopee-popup__close-btn').click()

time.sleep(2)

firstLevelMenu = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/ul[@class="navbar__links"]')
action.move_to_element(firstLevelMenu).perform();

secondLevelMenu = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Login')]");
secondLevelMenu.click();
```

Here are some of the programs that it failed to execute or find:

```
actions.move_to_element(knownElement, 10, 25).click().build().perform()
actions.click()
actions.perform()
nav = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('li["navbar__link navbar__link--account navbar__link--tappable navbar__link--hoverable navbar__link-text navbar__link-text--medium"]')
a = driver.findElement(By.linkText('Login'))
actions.move_to_element(nav).moveToElement(a)
time.sleep (1)
actions.click(a)
actions.perform()

nav = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('li["navbar__link navbar__link--account navbar__link--tappable navbar__link--hoverable navbar__link-text navbar__link-text--medium"]')
actions.move_to_element(nav).perform()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li[login]"))).click()                                       
continue_link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Login')

actions.move_to_element(continue_link)
actions.click(continue_link)
actions.perform()

driver.find_element_by_link_text("Login").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="navbar-wrapper container-wrapper"]//div[@class="container navbar"]/ul[@class="navbar__links"]//li[@class="navbar__link navbar__link--account navbar__link--tappable navbar__link--hoverable navbar__link-text navbar__link-text--medium"]//li[contains(text(),"Login")]').click(
```

I expect it to click. but all of them have pop out this error:

```py
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/ul[@class="navbar__links"]"}
```

This is always the result of it:

```py
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/ul[@class="navbar__links"]"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first attempt there are two problems

Missing `/` in the xpath `'/ul[@class="navbar__links"]'`, should be `'//ul[@class="navbar__links"]'`

The login button has `<li>` tag, not `<a>` tag, should be `'//li[contains(text(), "Login")]'`

```
firstLevelMenu = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//ul[@class="navbar__links"]')
action.move_to_element(firstLevelMenu).perform();

secondLevelMenu = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[contains(text(), "Login")]');
secondLevelMenu.click();
```

In the second attempt you are using invalid `css_selector`, you didn't mention the class attribute

```
nav = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('li[class="navbar__link navbar__link--account navbar__link--tappable navbar__link--hoverable navbar__link-text navbar__link-text--medium"]')
```

But it leads to two elements anyway, the `sign up` and `login`, so you will get the first one (the `sign up`). You should use the first approach.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the nav bar element using:

```
//ul[@class="navbar__links"]
```

Note: you have a single "/" while I have used "//" for xpath

Comment: yes try with //. Read about absolute xpath and relative xpath. You were trying to use absolute xpath with single /. Relative xpath starts with //